# Redux action is undefined outside the Promise

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been using async calls with Redux + Promise Middleware like this:

```
export function getAllFiles() {
  const request = axios.get(`${URL}/files`).then(res => res.data);

  return { type: "GET_FILES", payload: request };
}
```

So far it worked, since from my understanding Promise Middleware takes care of this. Also, if I `console.log(res.data)` inside `.then`, I will get expected result. However, when I check it from reducer file it's `undefined`. Can someone please school me if I'm missing something huge.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Info from "./../components/Info/info";
import { getAllFiles } from "./../actions";

class HomeContainer extends Component {
  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(getAllFiles);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <Info />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    files: state.files
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeContainer);






import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import fileReducer from "./file_reducer.js";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ wineReducer });
export default rootReducer;


// file_reducer.js

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_FILES":
      return {...state, files: action.payload}
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see why this doesn't work....but could you give an example of how you are firing the action?

Comment: I edited the file

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is your treating, what is clearly an [async action](https://redux.js.org/glossary#async-action),  as a synchronous one.

The redux store by default will only deal with action objects, in your case since you need to wait for a result *before* we fire the action object, we need some middleware to allow the store to handle this.

Have a look at the [applyMiddleware](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware) function, plenty of links to common thunk middleware and code samples.